# Running K8s cluster from Gitlab-runner on Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently I have a Kubernetes cluster prepared for using it with Gitlab-runner and its kubernetes executor and I want to use it from a different Openshift cluster, so I have two different and separated clusters.

I am currently running the Gitlab-runner image on an Openshift pod with a *config.toml* like this, following the docs in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#connecting-to-the-kubernetes-api:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 10
[[runners]]
  name = "size-XL"
  url = "https://blablabla/ci"
  token = "blablabla"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.kubernetes]
    namespace = "gitlab"
    privileged = false
    host= "https://blablabla:6443"
    cert_file= "/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem"
    key_file= "/etc/ssl/certs/key.pem"
    ca_keyfile= "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem"
    cpu_limit = "4"
    memory_limit = "6Gi"
    service_cpu_limit = "1"
    service_memory_limit = "2Gi"
    helper_cpu_limit = "2"
    helper_memory_limit = "2Gi"
    cpu_request = "1"
    memory_request = "2Gi"
    service_cpu_request = "250Mi"
    service_memory_request = "512Mi"
    helper_cpu_request = "250Mi"
    helper_memory_request = "512Mi"
    service-account = "test"
    service_account_overwrite_allowed = ".*"
    image = "blablabla"
```

My problem is that even if it is able to connect to the K8s cluster and start picking jobs, any time it does, I get this:

```
Checking for jobs... received                       job=17311 repo_url=https://blablabla.git runner=c36ccf98
WARNING: Preparation failed: error connecting to Kubernetes: ca file, cert file and key file must be specified when using file based auth  job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
Will be retried in 3s ...                           job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
WARNING: Preparation failed: error connecting to Kubernetes: ca file, cert file and key file must be specified when using file based auth  job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
Will be retried in 3s ...                           job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
WARNING: Preparation failed: error connecting to Kubernetes: ca file, cert file and key file must be specified when using file based auth  job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
Will be retried in 3s ...                           job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): error connecting to Kubernetes: ca file, cert file and key file must be specified when using file based auth job=17311 project=3128 runner=c36ccf98
```

I had no luck, any idea?

Comment: Have you added the 'edit' role to the 'default' account in that project? IOW, have you run ``oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z default``. If you don't do that, applications can't use the REST API and certainly not to create stuff.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton In fact I have. But I am afraid that this message might come from the K8s cluster and not from the Openshift cluster, so at least what I think is happening is that the K8s cluster is trying to use Openshifts service account, and that obviously does not exist on a different cluster.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't understand when you say 'k8s cluster' and characterise that as different to the OpenShift cluster. OpenShift is the k8s cluster, with extra stuff on top, it is not separate. Are you saying you have a completely seperate k8s cluster? If so, I don't understand how you are deploying across the two.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, maybe it was not clear enough, both clusters are different (even if Openshift has k8s below). According to https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#connecting-to-the-kubernetes-api you can connect a runner to a different k8s cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ca_keyfile= "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem"
```

was in fact the problem. because it is just `ca_file` instead of `ca_keyfile`